# How to list a degree and related certificate from 2 different universities in the same system?

Tags: resume, education

I completed a bachelor's degree from University A. This was an interdisciplinary program where students could choose from specializations in different fields like graphic design, computer animation, etc.

The specialization I wanted wasn't available at University A, so I got permission to complete it through University B. University A & B are both part of the same university system.

Due to a technicality, although my Uni B courses were used to satisfy Uni A's requirements, they don't show up in my transcript and the specialization doesn't show either. I have a separate transcript from Uni B that specifies that I completed the specialization.

What is the best way for me to display this on my resume? My final degree was obtained at Uni A, with the specialization/certificate through Uni B. I don't want to display Uni B separately, because it makes it look like the specialization was not part of my degree. I also don't want to leave Uni B out entirely, in case anyone tries to verify my education and things don't add up.

I'm thinking of writing something like this:

Bachelor's Degree in XYZ, Specialization in ABC

(ABC coursework was completed at sibling university, Uni B)

Answer (score 4):

What you proposed should be fine.

If they ask for details you can elaborate at that point. Don't go into excessive detail up front because it's most likely not relevant, anyway, and excessive verbosity might in fact be a turn off to other potential employers.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a short and punchy wording:

```
Northern U, Northern U Southeast
Bachelor's in Animation
Specialization: hair and fur simulation.
```

If you're a 3D Technical Artist or the like, those specializations are boss and you want it to stand out.  Congrats!